# Rails5 - what is the best approach for writing unit tests for services?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runit

In my app i have serveral services (pure ruby). what is the best approach to implement unit tests? shoiuld i implement additional unit tests for controllers, or create a separated tests only for services?

update - implemented solution:

1. dedicated tests for UserService (test/services/user_service_test
2. unit test for creating new employee includes verification if UserService.create_user_for_employee method is called. Test is based on Minitest::Mock. It requires 'minitest/autorun' (require 'minitest/autorun' in test_helper)

EmployeesControllerTest:

```
setup do
    #@employee = employees(:one)
    @new_employee = {name: 'name', surname: 'surname', email: 'email@email.com'}
    sign_in users(:admin1)
    @mock = UserService.new
  end

test "should create_employee" do
    assert_difference('Employee.count') do
      post employees_url, employee: @new_employee
    end

    @mock.stub :create_user_for_employee, true do
        assert(@mock.create_user_for_employee(@new_employee, 'user'))
    end

    assert_redirected_to employees_url
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have simple ruby classes inside your `/app/services` folder.
Then just write very simple unit test for each single service. 
Place them under `/test/services/` or `spec/services/` folder.
You should have one unit test file for each class you define for your application.

Comment: thx - that's what i expected to be the best solution. but - there is one issue. Let say that'inside employee_controller after employee.save you call method  UserService.new.create_user(@employee) - you want to automatically create user account for each new employee. In this case i guess that in my test "should create_employee" i should assert that the UserService method is called - but when i am looking at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html a don't see assertion for that....any idea how to do it?

Comment: @MaciekR what you're looking for are Mocks. If you're using `Test::Unit` you could include Mocha and write `UserService.expects(:new).once`. In Rspec it would be something like `expect(UserService).to receive(:new)`.

Comment: thx - i've updated my question with implementation based on your proposal.